# How can I make Leaflet tiles appear in a page?

Tags: leaflet, tiles

I am having trouble with leaflet working, but not displaying any of the background tiles in the page.

This one is using the leaflet-rails gem in a Rails app.
[image]

This is just in an html sample page:
[image]

I have tried every browser I have and I am not sure where to start --since apart from the backgrounds the map seems to be working fine.

Comment: Posting your problematic piece(s) of code and describing what you have tried will help you get better answers.

Comment: It turns out that the map api that I was calling was never being requested --when I switched to the link by @Jason Scheirer I got it working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What's the network tab in your browser tools telling you? Is it requesting tiles from a server? Is it returning an error message? Did you set the `tile_layer` parameter to something valid in your rails app before rendering to HTML? For example, `http://{s}.tile.osm.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png`?

Comment: Thanks -I had not even looked --the network never even sends a GET request for the tiles.  This is at least sending me in the right direction.  Using your link I can at least get the map working in a static page.  Now I might be able to figure out the leaflet-rails gem part.

Comment: The gem worked without the gem "Helpers" when I simply placed static code into the view.  It seems that the rest is an issue with the gem.  Thanks -@Jason Scheirer